# No TagKey: "<tag>" - User tags are ignored by cost explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cost-explorer

I want to group the following usages by a tag named "organization":

- Client VPN endpoint association hours
- Client VPN endpoint connection hours
- EC2 instances hours

So I set the "organization" tag on the following resources

- Client VPN endpoint
- EC2 instances

I also activated the user-defined cost allocation tags in the Billing panel.

Although, when i group my resources using the "organization" tag, here is the output I get :
[image]

Seems like none of my resources have the "organization" tag defined, although it's absolutely not the case. For example, this is a shortened `describe-vpn-endpoints` output :

```json
{
    "ClientVpnEndpoints": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "Code": "available"
            },
            "ClientCidrBlock": "10.1.0.0/16",
            "SplitTunnel": false,
            "VpnProtocol": "openvpn",
            "TransportProtocol": "udp",
            "VpnPort": 443,
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "app",
                    "Value": "xxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "organization",
                    "Value": "630c8acfd564a41dae9d73e1"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "o-ABEFO_XXXXXXX-630c8acfd564a41dae9d73e1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Code": "pending-associate"
            },
            "CreationTime": "2022-08-30T12:55:51",
            "ClientCidrBlock": "10.1.0.0/16",
            "SplitTunnel": true,
            "VpnProtocol": "openvpn",
            "TransportProtocol": "udp",
            "VpnPort": 443,
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "app",
                    "Value": "xxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "organization",
                    "Value": "630e0787814fdcf162bd521f"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "xxxxxx-o-flomo-630e0787814fdcf162bd521f"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your problem, but I have this issue when my tag not showing on cost explore, and later figure out how to fix it.

I want to track each S3 bucket cost and set the tag following this document.
Link: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-find-bucket-cost

After the tag is active, wait 24 hours and it will show on cost explore.

On the Cost Explorer ----> Report parameters (on the right-hand side) you can do the filter.

```
Important: It looks like it will only show the time of cost after the tag applies.
e.g  I activate the tag at Feb 9th, if I use cost explore to do the filtering,
it will only start the cost from Feb 9th.
```

1. on the `Group by` ---> `Dimension`, choose the `Tag`, and then choose the `Tag` you create.
2. Choose the service related to the tag
3. Choose tag and `excludes` this one `No tag key: xxx`, so it will include all the S3 buckets you tag.

Here is the final result:

[image: Each-S3-Tag-Cost-Explorer]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yvette Lau's answer contains the real reason, but one could miss it. Cost Explorer only applies the tagging starting from the date when you enabled cost tagging. So, even if your resources have had tags for a long time already, cost explorer will show "no tag key" for all the previous days when cost tagging was not enabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).